# internet explorer gives out: "object doesn't support this property"

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following, which basically loads data dynamically from variable 'href' into a specified div container.

```
setTimeout(function() {
      $.get(href, function(source) {
        var html = $(source);
        content = html.find("#content").html();
        $("#content").html(content);
        $("#content").animate({marginLeft: "0px"}, 1000);
        $("#ajax-loader").fadeOut(150);
    });
      }, 500);
```

Works perfectly on Firefox, Chrome, etc, but doesn't seem to work on IE 8.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the line var html=$(source) doing?

Comment: takes the response from the get request (so it makes a jquery object out of an html page)

Answer (score 0):

It means that one of the methods used on an object doesn't exist. Have you tried commenting out rule by rule do determine on which rule the error occurs?

Comment: I second this the IE has a good debugger to step through the code.